# Power BI Filters- remove second line

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Is there a way to remove the second line `is (All)` completely from the filter card?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can hide the entire filter pane from user view. Use filter visuals with "single select".

[image]

[image]

Comment: I need the filter so I cannot hide it. "single select" still does not hide the "is ...." second line on the filter. Is that customizability not possible at the moment?